# What are the different currencies in Apex Legends and how are they earned?

Tags: apex-legends

After playing Apex Legends, I seem to have accumulated some of each of the three in-game currencies that are listed in the corner of the lobby screens.

[image]

On the Store screen I see some items for sale for the orange currencies, and some for yellow currencies. However, I'm not sure how each currency is earned, and why some purchases require one or another.

What are the different currencies in Apex Legends, and what are the differences in how they can be earned and what they can be used to purchase?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Apex Coins** [image]
can be purchased with real-world money, or earned as part of Battle Pass. They can be used to purchase cosmetics from the Featured section of the Store, purchase Apex Packs containing semi-random cosmetics and sometimes Crafting Materials, or unlock new Legends.

**Legend Tokens** [image]
can only be earned by leveling up (or refilling your XP bar at max level). They can be used to unlock new Legends, or purchase cosmetics in the Exclusive section of the the Store.

**Crafting Metals** [image]
are randomly included in some Apex Packs. 45 Apex Packs can by earned by reaching certain player levels, or they can be purchased with Apex Coins, or they can be earned as seasonal and Battle Pass rewards. Apex Coins can be used to directly purchase any generally-available (not exclusive or seasonal) cosmetic item in the game from the Armory and Legends screens.